# How to save field values of Contact Form 7 plugin in database?

Tags: php, wordpress

I have want to save field value of **Contact Form 7** plugin in database using this code:

```
add_action('wpcf7_before_send_mail', my_conversion($cf7));

function my_conversion($cf7)   
{   
    $name = $cf7->posted_data["your-name"];   
    $email = $cf7->posted_data["your-email"];   
    $Work = $cf7->posted_data["tel-Work"];    
    $homenumber = $cf7->posted_data["homenumber"];   
    $mobilenumber = $cf7->posted_data["mobilenumber"];

    mysql_query("INSERT INTO `hello` (`Your Name`, `Work`, `Home`, `Mobile No`, `Email`) VALUES ('$name',$Work,$homenumber,$mobilenumber,$email)");    
}
```

but its not working, here's the error:

```
"`$cf7->posted_data["...."]`;" can not fetch values.
```

Answer (score 2):

This is wrong:

`add_action('wpcf7_before_send_mail', my_conversion($cf7));`

It should be:

```
add_action('wpcf7_before_send_mail', 'my_conversion');
```

To know what values are available in your `$cf7` object, add `var_dump( $cf7 );` at the beginning of your `my_conversion` function.

DO NOT USE [`mysql_query`](http://php.net/manual/en/function.mysql-query.php)! Use the [`WPDB Class`](http://codex.wordpress.org/Class_Reference/wpdb) instead.

And lastly, there's the [Flamingo Plugin](http://wordpress.org/plugins/flamingo/) which saves your form automatically upon submission.

Answer (score 0):

yous should try using wp prepared query instead of direct query

```
$name = $cf7->posted_data["your-name"];
$work = $cf7->posted_data["tel-Work"];

$email = $cf7->posted_data["your-email"];

$wpdb->query( $wpdb->prepare( 
    "
        INSERT INTO $wpdb->hello
        ( contact, email , name )
        VALUES ( %d, %s, %s )
    ", 
        $work, 
    $email , 
    $name 
) );
```

Comment: Thank you for your help but when i m using your insert query like this:

$wpdb->query( $wpdb->prepare( " INSERT INTO $wpdb->hello ( Your Name, Work , Home, Mobile No, Email) VALUES ( %s, %d, %d, %d, %s ) ", $fname, $work, $homenumber, $mobilenumber, $email ) );

i am getting this error:

"Call to a member function query() on a non-object"